# Basemap python. Проблема с установкой через pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, matplotlib, pip

Привет. У меня возникла проблема с установкой basemap (пакет для python, который входит в набор matplotlib для визуализации геоданных). Я люблю pip, поэтому решил воспользоваться именно им. В итоге, я получаю примерно одинаковое всякий раз при запуске. Замечу, что устанавливаю я этот пакет на python2.7. Ответ на команду:

> sudo pip2 install basemap
>
> Collecting basemap   Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement basemap (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
> for basemap

Поиск решений привёл к тому, что на [официальном сайте basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) фигурируют зависимости, которые pip2, по идее, должен сам разрешать, но почему-то не разрешил:

- PROJ4 Cartographic Projections Library.
- GEOS
- Pillow

GEOS установился отдельной командой:

> sudo pip2 install geos

Все остальные друзья, к сожалению, не устанавливаются.

Непосредственная установка из репозитория тоже покаким-то причинам не лечит ситуацию. Некоторые советы можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/251) и [тут](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/198).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение я нашёл [здесь](https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/).

> sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
>
> sudo apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap

Замечу, что изначально, перед установкой basemap могут помочь следующие действия:

- Удалить matplotlib и установить заново указанной мной командой (не через pip)
- Удалить basemap, geos или иной другой пакет из списка выше. После чего следует установить basemap, как я указал.

Можно запустить тестовый пример:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=50, lon_0=-100, resolution='l', area_thresh=1000.0)
map.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

[image: Результат]

Answer (score 0):

Из-за подложек, идущих в комплекте с Basemap, пакет был признан слишком большим, чтобы размещаться на pypi.org. Ссылка https://pypi.org/simple/basemap/ указывает на файл, не содержащий ссылок на архивы.

Остается три способа установить пакет

1. Установить пакет из репозитория операционной системы
2. Установить пакет из репозитория Anaconda
3. Установить пакет из исходных кодов на GitHub

Архивы с исходным кодом basemap хранятся на GitHub. Последнюю версию можно найти на странице [с релизами](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases/).

Необходимо установить заголовочные файлы библиотеки GEOS. После этого можно вызывать pip, указав прямую ссылку на GitHub

```
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.1.0.tar.gz
```